# Specify type annotations.dart(always_specify_types) - не пойму что от меня хочет Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_weather_app/weather_overview.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(       
        body: OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, orientation) {
            if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
              return WeatherOverview();
            }
            else {
              return WeatherOverview();
            }
          };
        )
      )
    );
  }
  }
```

Здравствуйте! VS-Code подчеркивает "builder: (context, orientation)". Подскажите пожалуйста какой тип и где указать, перепробовал всё что можно, и перечитал документацию, не пойму ничего, почему ошибка?

Comment: Приложите код из файла `weather_overview.dart`, а именно `WeatherOverview()` и все то отчего он зависит. Скорее всего там не хватает какой-то реализации.

Comment: https://github.com/maxmitchenko/weather_app_flutter.git

Comment: я добавлял тип dynamic, вроде перестало подчёркивать, но код не работает.....((

Comment: Добавил ответ, посмотрите.

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget OrientationWidgetBuilder(BuildContext context, Orientation orientation)
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OrientationWidgetBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал запустить код (см. скриншот ниже). Все работает, ничего не подчеркивает, проблема явно не в коде. Возможно вы используете старую версию Flutter (сейчас актуальная: `1.9.1+hotfix4`), или само приложение было создано на старой версии. (Для обновления Flutter используйте следующую комаду в CMD: `flutter upgrade`)

Как вариант ещё можно попробовать создать проект заново.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home:
            Scaffold(body: OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
          if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
            return WeatherOverview();
          } else {
            return WeatherOverview();
          }
        })));
  }
}

class WeatherOverview extends StatelessWidget {
  final _weatherProvider = WeatherProvider();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Weather Overview"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Weather>(
          future: _weatherProvider.getCurrentWeather(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return WeatherContainer(weather: snapshot.data);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WeatherProvider {
  Future<Weather> getCurrentWeather() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Kharkiv&units=metric&APPID=1ea55013049215603ece3fee22806975');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Weather.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load weather data');
    }
  }
}

class Weather {
  final int temperature;
  final String locationName;
  final String iconUrl;

  Weather(this.temperature, this.locationName, this.iconUrl);

  Weather.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : temperature = json['main']['temp'],
        locationName = json['name'],
        iconUrl = _generateIconUrl(json['weather'][0]['icon']);

  static String _generateIconUrl(String icon) {
    return 'https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/$icon@2x.png';
  }
}

class WeatherContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Weather weather;

  WeatherContainer({Key key, @required this.weather})
      : assert(weather != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          '${weather.locationName} - ${weather.temperature} °C',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        Image.network(weather.iconUrl),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Работ приложения]
[image: Работ приложения при перевернутом экране]

Comment: Хм, странно.... А ориентация у Вас меняется при переворачивании эмулятора?

Comment: @MaxMit да, добавил фото в ответ.

Comment: @MaxMit выполните `flutter clean` в проекте, возможно поможет.